# Barcode printer printing plain text instead of barcodes

Tags: printing

I have an [Argox OS-214plus](http://www.argox.com/product/os-214plus/) PPLB barcode printer configured to work with a Point of Sale software called Poswizard.

The issue is that it's printing plain text where It should print barcodes.

[image: a barcode sticker, and a sticker with some text on it in quotation marks]

The first one above is printed from Windows 7 and the second one is printed from Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I assume the problem you are experiencing is that your barcode printer seems to print text instead of the barcode? Can you please edit your question to make it more clear? Secondarily, I doubt anybody would be able to help you if you don't specify the hardware model and the software you are using

Comment: Ok i did what you said

Comment: Without more information, your issue seems to be really hard to solve. Would be nice if you could specify if the device printed barcodes correctly in the past, which version of Ubuntu are you using, the way in which the printer connects to the computer and the purpose of the software.

Comment: You'll need to make sure your printer driver and your printer are configured to the same command language. Also see if bar codes have to be downloaded on startup and you are selecting available bar codes such as Code 3 of 9, etc. that are installed.

Comment: when installing the printer on windows* it is basically just plug and play with a argox os-214 plus PPLA bat when install a argox os-214 plus PPLB there is a template file in the software folder that u can edit so that the printer prints correctly

Comment: this is the template file for a argox os-214 plus PPLB

o
N
R100,0
A450,150,1,1,4,2,N,$NAME1
A400,150,1,1,4,2,N,$NAME2
A360,490,1,1,10,3,N,$PRICE
B330,170,1,2,2,6,70,B,$NUMBER

Comment: this is the template file for a argox os-214 plus PPLA
 
;1 2 3 4 567 8901 2345
;a b c d eee ffff gggg [hhhh iiii] jj..j <cr>
;a = rotation
;b = font or barcode id
;c = font width multiplier or bardcode wide bar
;d = font height multiplier or barcode narrow bar
;eee = bar code hieght
;fff = row position
;ggg = colomn position
;
!qA
!c0000
!KI503
!O0220
!f220
!KW0390
!KI70
!V0
!L
*H13
*PC
*A2
D11
;
422200000800035$NAME1
422200000800060$NAME2
434200000800120$PRICE
1F4202003170018$NUMBER
;
;Q
;E

Comment: @MatthewDuPreez: sorry for tha late reply. Can you edit your question to show the output of `lpstat -p -d`?

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include the templates you posted on the comments.